# DataTable adding column doesn't add row?

Tags: c#, datatable

I need a bit of a steer on this DataTable concept. I'm storing data in a DataTable which I initialise by first adding a column like so:

```
DataTable outputData = new DataTable();
outputData.Columns.Add("Reference/Group");
```

Now if I write this out to a CSV file (using my own class), I get what you'd expect, a view in spreadsheet software like:

```
             A
 1    Reference/Group
```

Yet when I go on in my script to assume that row 1 exists (by referencing `outputData.Rows[0]`) I get:

```
Exception: There is no row at position 0.
```

However if I try to add a row with the above content, it complains there's no column. If I specify the column then add a row, I can reference `Rows[0]` but by then I've got TWO rows like:

```
             A
 1    Reference/Group
 2    Some new row
```

What's the correct approach here and what is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
outputData.Columns[0].ColumnName
```

instead of

```
outputData.Rows[0]
```

Because `outputData.Columns.Add("Reference/Group");` will not generate new row for you. And you are using column name for `A1` cell, not row data

Answer (score 1):

All this says is that your custom "export" code displays column name in first CSV row. It has nothing to do with the actual data inside `DataTable`.
There are in fact 0 rows in Your table before you insert any of them.